# Cython Behavior difference setup.py develop vs setup.py install with shared object artifact

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, setup.py

I noticed that setup.py develop will create the cython shared object (.so file) whereas setup.py install will not. Both will cythonize the .pyx file, but it seems only develop will generate the build artifact.

The code in setup.py in question looks like this:

```
extra_compile_args = ["/O2" if os.name == "nt" else "-O3"]

extension = Extension("modulename.filename", ["modulename/filename.pyx"],
                      extra_compile_args=extra_compile_args)

setup(
    ...
    ext_modules=cythonize([extension]),
    ...
)
```

Any idea why this would be the case? Any idea how to get the binary produced when using `install`?

Comment: Setuptools is always a bit of a mystery to me (so I'm not completely sure), but I think: `install` builds the files out of the working source tree, and then installs the module elsewhere on the Python path so you can import it. `develop` builds the files and puts them in the current directory (and then links that directory into the Python path I think). So that's probably what you're seeing